# Select Option Value is undefined in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have 4 dependencies select options, I can get the first `<select>` value using jQuery, the remained 3 options return undefined, I tried many ways to get the values using jQuery starting from the parent tags to the tag itself with no luck, here is my code:-
jQuery:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('URL',function(data){
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(data);
      jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
        $('#hospitalID')
            .append($("<option id='optionData"+v.id+"'></option>")
            .attr("value",v.id)
            .text(v.name));
      });
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#depID option[value!="0"]').remove();
    $('#hospitalID').change(function(){
        var hospitalID = $("option:selected:last",'#hospitalID').val();
        hospitalID = encodeURIComponent(hospitalID);
        jQuery.get(URL"+hospitalID,function(data){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#depID').find('option[value!="0"]').remove();
        console.log(data);

            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                //if($('#optionData'+value.departmentID).length == 0){
                console.log(value.departmentID);
                    $('#depID')
                        .append($("<option id='optionData"+value.departmentID+"'></option>")
                        .attr("value",value.departmentID)
                        .text(value.name));
                        //}
                    });
              });
        });
    });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#depID option[value!="0"]').remove();
    $('#depID').change(function(){
        var hospitalID = $("option:selected:last",'#hospitalID').val();
        var depID = $("option:selected:last",'#depID').val();
        hospitalID = encodeURIComponent(hospitalID);
        console.log(depID);
        jQuery.get("URL"+hospitalID+"/"+depID,function(data){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#drID').find('option[value!="0"]').remove();
        console.log(data);

            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                //if($('#optionData'+value.departmentID).length == 0){
                console.log(value.doctorID);
                    $('#drID')
                        .append($("<option id='optionData"+value.doctorID+"'></option>")
                        .attr("value",value.doctorID)
                        .text(value.drName));
                        //}
                    });
              });
        });
    });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#depID option[value!="0"]').remove();
    $('#drID').change(function(){
        var drID = $("option:selected:last",'#drID').val();
        drID = encodeURIComponent(drID);
        console.log(drID);
        jQuery.get("/URL/"+drID,function(data){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#drAppID').find('option[value!="0"]').remove();
        console.log(data);

            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                //if($('#optionData'+value.departmentID).length == 0){
                console.log(value.doctorID);
                    $('#drAppID')
                        .append($("<option id='optionData"+value.id+"'></option>")
                        .attr("value",value.id)
                        .text(value.dates));
                        //}
                    });
              });
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:-

```
   <div data-role="page" class="mobileBody">
  <?php require 'user_header.php' ?>
  <div data-role="main" class="absolute-center">
      <label for="hospitals">Hospital</label>
      <select id="hospitalID" data-native-menu="true">
        <option value="0"></option>
      </select>

      <label for="depID">Departments</label>
      <select id="depID">
        <option value="0"></option>
      </select>

      <label for="drID">Doctors</label>
      <select id="drID">
        <option value="0"></option>
      </select>

      <label for="drAppID">Doctor Appointments</label>
      <select id="drAppID">
        <option value="0"></option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u post your log in there console.log(data);

Comment: I'm getting the expected objects and they are right, but the values of select options are undefined except the first one!

Comment: So, you get exception when you want to get department list and set them select tag, am i right?

Comment: No, I can set all of them correctly in that dynamic way, but their values are undefined while trying to access them via jQuery as below:-
var depID = $("option:selected:last",'#depID').val(); // this value is undefined, the same for drName

Comment: can you test this $( "#depID option:selected" ).val(); for getting selected deparment

Comment: The result is undefined as below from the console:-
$( "#depID option:selected" ).val();
undefined

Comment: $( "#depID" ).val(); it's also right when selected selectbox item, and aslo you can add your all js script in one  $(document).ready(function(){ });

Comment: Thanks for your investigation bro. I am using Ripple Emulator for testing and it has many <select> tags, so my selects were not reachable! I tried $('select') only in the console I saw a lot of select tags which are not mine, and mine are not there! ... 
Ripple Emulator Bug!! we have to Fork for that issue... 
Many thanks for your help :)